# django foreign key в urls

Tags: django, сервер, django-rest-framework

Существуют 2 модели, у одной из них есть поле ForeignKey примерно так:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    customer = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer

class Element(models.Model):
    count = models.IntegerField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey('Table', on_delete = models.CASCADE

    def __str__(self):
        return self.owner.customer + " " + str(self.id)
```

во views я хочу отфильтровать элементы относящиеся к определенной Table:

```
class ElementsDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request, owner):
        elements = Element.objects.filter(owner=owner)
        data = ElementSerializer(elements, many=True).data
        return Response(data)
```

вопрос в том что мне надо ввести в urls, чтобы передать этого ownera для фильтрации:

```
path('elements_detail/<что тут ввести?>/', ElementsDetail.as_view(), name="elements_detail"),
```

ну или любой другой способ чтобы отфильтровать элементы например по id owerа или как нибудь по другому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов - передавать в урл `id` экземпляра `Table`

```
path('elements_detail/<int:id>/', ElementsDetail.as_view(), name="elements_detail"),
```

Нужно исправить **views**

```
class ElementsDetail(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        elements = Element.objects.filter(owner__id=self.kwargs['id'])
        data = ElementSerializer(elements, many=True).data
        return Response(data)
```